# What is the meaning of CHECKDB=FALSE in MSI?

Tags: windows-installer

When running an MSI through the command line what does passing the arguement "CHECKDB=FALSE" really do?

The MSI of course can be anything from Microsoft, to Compuware DevPartner, to a programmer compiled MSI from .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running an MSI with that parameter would set the public property named CHECKDB equal to a false value. I have not seen that particular property before and I don't see any reference to it online. I suspect that it is specific to the MSI that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but CHECKDB could be a property added to Installshield's default template file. Since many setups are made based on those templates, you would end up with the property showing up in many MSI files. I suspect that it might be used by Installshield's SQLServer deployment features, and if I were to guess I think setting the property to FALSE would skip some custom actions related to database deployment.